# "Free Vector" for commercial use ALTERED

Tags: vector

If you find "Free Vectors" online and change the color scheme or tweak it a little and then used it for commercial use would that still be grounds for violation of copyright?

Comment: What do you mean by "Free Vectors" that doesn't mean anything without more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This would depend *completely* upon the license provided by the "free vector".

With some license there would be zero infringement.

With other licenses it would be an infringement entirely.

Note that *there is **no such thing*** as "change it by [x] amount and it's okay." That is a myth.